# Can access production database from Rails console but not Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise

When I try to login to my Devise app using the rails console on my production database, I can with no trouble, however I cannot when using my Rails App.

I launch my Rails Console with `rails c -e production`, from my home environment (not SSHing int it or anything) and then proceed to execute `app.post('/users/sign_in', {"user"=>{"email"=>"email", "password"=>"password"}})`, which succeeds with:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-10 05:37:31 +0000
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-10 05:37:31 +0000
Processing by DeviseSessionsController#create as HTML
Processing by DeviseSessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"amar@sittr.co.nz", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"amar@sittr.co.nz", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Redirected to http://www.example.com/dashboard
Redirected to http://www.example.com/dashboard
Completed 302 Found in 1830ms (ActiveRecord: 1426.3ms)
Completed 302 Found in 1830ms (ActiveRecord: 1426.3ms)
 => 302
```

From which I can then use `app.get '/dashboard'` which is a password protected page, and then succeeds with:

```
Started GET "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-10 05:38:14 +0000
Started GET "/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-10 05:38:14 +0000
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.haml within layouts/application (139.6ms)
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.haml within layouts/application (139.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6370ms (Views: 686.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5087.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6370ms (Views: 686.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5087.6ms)
 => 200
```

This is all working as expected, except for when I try and go to the production site, and sign in with the same credentials, it gives me a 500 error `Errno::ECONNREFUSEDdevise_sessions#create
Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200`. What confuses me is that this says it is trying to connect to `localhost` which wouldn't make any sense. The following is my `database.yml` file (with the sensitive bits taken out):

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db_name
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: rds.database.com
  port: 5432
  username: username
  password: password
```

As you can see, I have set the port and host correctly. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Double check our port, cause it differ in 9200 and 5432

Comment: How do I check the port? My `database.yml` file says what the port should be.

Comment: Check that you can access your app from browser

Comment: I should have said that It all works fine when I run `rails s -e production` on my local machine, which would mean that I am using the database listed in my `database.yml` `production` section.

Comment: It's likely going to be an authentication issue -- where's your production database hosted?

Comment: Amazon RDS Singapore - Postgresql Beta Version.